# How to access ActiveRecord hash column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I access an ActiveRecord column that is a hash through the rails console? I am trying to get the `properties` column.

Example:

```
=> #<Ahoy::Event:0x007ffde80e3088
 id: "abc123def465ghi798j9",
 visit_id: "098dca809oiu567hjg678jh",
 user_id: 26,
 name: "click",
 properties:
  {"host"=>"localhost/sponsors",
   "name"=>"click",
   "type"=>"post-to-host",
   "value"=>0,
   "target"=>"whereintheworldiscarmonsandiego.com/rd/r.php",
   "partner"=>"Uber",
   "trigger"=>"click",
   "utm_source"=>1234567890,
   "utm_campaign"=>"organic"},
 time: Fri, 06 May 2016 21:42:23 UTC +00:00,
 user_type: "Applicant">
```

I am attempting:

semi/pseudo code

```
Ahoy::Event.where(properties["type"]: "post-to-host")
```

Comment: This is a PostgreSQL database with a `jsonb` column called `properties`?

Answer (score -1):

if this is a sequel style database.. you can't. the issue with serializing a column (using a hash column) is that youre bypassing the intrinsic sequel abstractions. which means you can't search by that column (effectively).

You can either break out properties to a relationship or do some really hacky stuff like

```
Ahoy::Event.where('properties LIKE ?', {type: 'post-to-host'})
```

essentially, whats happening is that the column is actually stored as a yaml formatted string, and when you access it in ruby, it just serializes the string from yaml, so in order to query on it, you'd have to query it like a string which will be pretty ineffective and generally error prone.

tl;dr dont use hash columns (serialize) for data you intend to query on

Comment: You are correct in your statement that it is not possible to access with SQL style DB. Although, this will return the tables: `Ahoy::Event.where("properties ->> 'type' = ?", 'host-and-post')` I could not get a working solution with your line of code.

Comment: `serialize` may or may not be used, the comment above suggests that this is PostgreSQL with a `jsonb` column and if that's the case then no ugly `serizialize` or YAML kludges are needed.

Answer (score -1):

In Ahoy, we have built method to access json properties. You cn try following syntax:
1. Ahoy::Event.where_properties(type: "post-to-host")
2. Ahoy::Event.where_props(type: "post-to-host")